# Capturing mouse Enter / Leave in designtime

Tags: delphi

I'm facing some difficulties to capture mouse events for a TCustomPanel component at designtime. I've tried the 
`CMDesignHitTest` returning `Message.Result := 1`. It works ok capturing when mouse enters the component, but fails to sense when mouse leaves. I've tried also messing with the component style, but this does not work at all. I understand (from what I gather on the Web), that after returning `Message.Result := 1` on the `CMDesignHitTest` event, all mouse events are captured by the component, but it seems not to work with the standard `OnMouseEnter` / `OnMouseLeave` events. I wonder if anyone can get me a working sample about this issue. I thank very much in advance.

Comment: As a component developer, you shouldn't be using the standard OnMouseEnter and OnMouseLeave events anyway. Those are for the component *user*, and at design time, they'll be hooked up to special placeholders the IDE makes up to refer to functions in the user's code. So forget about events: Which specific *message* are you trying to detect in your component at design time?

Comment: You did not say which version of Delphi you are using. In older versions, `CM_MOUSELEAVE` was broken and did not always get issued even though `CM_MOUSEENTER` worked fine. That was fixed in a later version by having the VCL call `TrackMouseEvent()` to receive `WM_MOUSELEAVE` messages to help trigger `CM_MOUSELEAVE` messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a test, try adding a handler for the `WM_NCHITTEST` message and make sure that its `Message.Result` is getting set to `HTCLIENT` when the `csDesigning` flag is enabled in the `ComponentState` property.  I saw some online articles that suggest `HTCLIENT` is needed in order for `CM_DESIGNHITTEST` to work.